# Cant open project when I click the app

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I try to open `C:\Users\user\Downloads\NYP\NYP\app`, it always show `C:\Users\user\Downloads\NYP\NYP` instead. How to solve this?

Edit: 
I have this path `C:\Users\user\Downloads\NYP\NYP\app` that opens the app.
However , whenever I click on this path, it leads me to open up  `C:\Users\user\Downloads\NYP\NYP` instead which is to bring the path up a level

Comment: can you be more specific please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should open the project as C:\Users\user\Downloads\NYP\NYP only. The app folder is a part of it. Once the project opens, choose Android in the top left drop down above the file directory.